Django on CapRover Creates Local Directory Instead of Uploading Media to S3
I'm deploying a Django application using CapRover, and I'm running into an issue with django-storages s3 bucket. When I run the app locally, everything works fine, and media files are uploaded to my S3 bucket as expected. However, when I deploy the app to CapRover, Django creates a local directory named https:/bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/media/ and stores the uploaded media files there instead of uploading them to S3.
Here's my settings.py configuration:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', '')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME', '')

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'project.storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project.storages.MediaStorage'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I tried removing MEDIA_ROOT, but then it just created the media folder directly without the https: and link folder.
